# Relative Line Numbers in Xcode

Tags: xcode, vim

I'm just getting started with Xcode. I've installed the [XVim](https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim) plugin to provide Vim keybindings. However, I'm missing the ability to turn on relative line numbers. In vim, this is done with `:set relativenumber`, and in Visual Studio, there's a plugin for it.

Is there anything like this for Xcode?

Comment: I don't have XCode at the moment but it seems like you should be able to enable it somehow. XVim contains the functionality already to do this.

Comment: See my answer. It never occurred to me to actually try `:set relativenumber`! I was looking for a menu option.

Comment: This is mentioned in here too https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim/blob/master/Documents/Users/FeatureList.md

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wowza. It never occurred to me that I could just use Vim syntax for this!

To enable relative line numbers in XCode with XVim:

`set relativenumber`

Comment: you can also use the shorthand inside Xcode with `:set rn`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xvim-developers/UzvJIOj6Ajc), I would answer "no and don't hold your breath for it".

Comment: Going through the issue tracker it seems this got merged in already. https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim/issues/557

Answer (score 0):

I found this setting if you want to add relative line numbers to the Xcode vim mode under the 'Editor' menu:

[image: editor menu to add relative line numbers]